# Cassini/WebServer.WebDev, NUnit and AppDomainUnloadedException

Tags: .net, nunit, cassini

I am using Cassini/WebServer.WebDev to run some automated tests of a WebService using NUnit.

I am not doing anything fancy, just

```
public class WebService{
  Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Server _server;

  public void Start(){
    _server = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Server(_port, "/", _physicalPath);
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    if (_server != null)
    {
      _server.Stop();
      _server = null;
    }
  }
}
[TestFixture]
public void TestFixture{
  [Test]
  public void Test(){
    using(WebService webService = new WebService()){
      webService.Start();
      // actual test invoking the webservice
    }
  }
}
```

, but when I run it using nunit-console.exe, I get the following output:

```
NUnit version 2.5.0.9015 (Beta-2)
Copyright (C) 2002-2008 Charlie Poole.\r\nCopyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newki
rk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.\r\nCopyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig
.\r\nAll Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment -
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.0.6001 Service Pack 1
  CLR Version: 2.0.50727.1434 ( Net 2.0.50727.1434 )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Default
Execution Runtime: net-2.0.50727.1434
.....
Tests run: 5, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0 Time: 28,4538451 seconds
  Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0


Unhandled exceptions:
1) TestCase1 : System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.
2) TestCase2 : System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.
3) TestCase3 : System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.
4) TestCase4 : System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.
```

If I run nunit-console under the debugger, I get the following output in the debug console:

```
[...]
The thread 0x1974 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
############################################################################
##############                 S U C C E S S               #################
############################################################################
Executed tests       : 5
Ignored tests        : 0
Failed tests         : 0
Unhandled exceptions : 4
Total time           : 25,7092944 seconds
############################################################################
The thread 0x1bd4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x10f8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1a80) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
A first chance exception of type 'System.AppDomainUnloadedException' occurred in System.Web.dll
##### Unhandled Exception while running 
System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.HostingEnvironmentShutdownComplete(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost)
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.OnAppDomainUnload(Object unusedObject, EventArgs unusedEventArgs)
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in System.Web.dll
The thread 0x111c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[0x1A64] nunit-console.exe: Managed' has exited with code -100 (0xffffff9c).
```

Do anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: Not a /good/ solution, but I ended up setting failonerror="false" on the NUnit-task and postprocessing the xml-output with a separate tools, that ignored the unhandled AppDomainUnloadedException.

Comment: I've uploaded an example solution demonstrating the problem to the appropriate NUnit bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunitv2/+bug/423611 . it'd be great if you could try that out and cross-check its validity (and post your findings to launchpad)

Comment: For reference, this is also reported in the comments on http://haacked.com/archive/2006/12/12/Using_WebServer.WebDev_For_Unit_Tests.aspx and http://blogs.dovetailsoftware.com/blogs/kmiller/archive/2007/11/07/unit-testing-a-web-service.aspx

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, but was not using Cassini. Instead, I had my own web server hosting based on `System.Net.HttpListener` with ASP.Net support through `System.Web.HttpRuntime` running in a different application domain created via `System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost()`. This is essentially the way Cassini works, except that Cassini works at the socket layer and implements a lot of the functionality provided by `System.Net.HttpListener` itself.

Anyway, to solve my problem, I needed to call `System.Web.HttpRuntime.Close()` before letting NUnit unload my application domain. I did this by exposing a new `Close()` method in my host proxy class that is invoked by the [TearDown] method of my [SetupFixture] class and that method calls `System.Web.HttpRuntime.Close()`.

I looked at the Cassini implementation through .Net Reflector and, although it uses `System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest()`, it doesn't seem to call `System.Web.HttpRuntime.Close()` anywhere.

I'm not exactly sure how you can keep using the pre-built Cassini implementation (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Server`), as you need to get the `System.Web.HttpRuntime.Close()` call to occur within the application domain created by Cassini to host ASP.Net.

For reference, here are some pieces of my working unit test with embedded web hosting.

My `WebServerHost` class is a very small class that allows marshaling requests into the application domain created by `System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost()`.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Hosting;

public class WebServerHost :
    MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void
    Close()
    {
        HttpRuntime.Close();
    }

    public void
    ProcessRequest(WebServerContext context)
    {
        HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(new WebServerRequest(context));
    }
}
```

The `WebServerContext` class is simply a wrapper around a `System.Net.HttpListenerContext` instance that derives from System.MarshalByRefObject to allow calls from the new ASP.Net hosting domain to call back into my domain.

```
using System;
using System.Net;

public class WebServerContext :
    MarshalByRefObject
{
    public
    WebServerContext(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    //  public methods and properties that forward to HttpListenerContext omitted

    private HttpListenerContext
    context;
}
```

The `WebServerRequest` class is just an implementation of the abstract `System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest` class that calls back into my domain from the ASP.Net hosting domain via the `WebServerContext` class.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

class WebServerRequest :
    HttpWorkerRequest
{
    public
    WebServerRequest(WebServerContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    //  implementation of HttpWorkerRequest methods omitted; they all just call
    //  methods and properties on context

    private WebServerContext
    context;
}
```

The `WebServer` class is a controller for starting and stopping the web server. When started, the ASP.Net hosting domain is created with my `WebServerHost` class as a proxy to allow interaction. A `System.Net.HttpListener` instance is also started and a separate thread is started to accept connections. When connections are made, a worker thread is started in the thread pool to handle the request, again via my `WebServerHost` class. Finally, when the web server is stopped, the listener is stopped, the controller waits for the thread accepting connections to exit, and then the listener is closed. **Finally, the HTTP runtime is also closed via a call into the `WebServerHost.Close()` method.**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Hosting;

class WebServer
{
    public static void
    Start()
    {
        lock ( typeof(WebServer) )
        {
            //  do not start more than once
            if ( listener != null )
                return;

            //  create web server host in new AppDomain
            host =
                (WebServerHost)ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost
                (
                    typeof(WebServerHost),
                    "/",
                    Path.GetTempPath()
                );

            //  start up the HTTP listener
            listener = new HttpListener();
            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8182/");
            listener.Start();

            acceptConnectionsThread = new Thread(acceptConnections);
            acceptConnectionsThread.Start();
        }
    }

    public static void
    Stop()
    {
        lock ( typeof(WebServer) )
        {
            if ( listener == null )
                return;

            //  stop listening; will cause HttpListenerException in thread blocked on GetContext()  
            listener.Stop();

            //  wait connection acceptance thread to exit
            acceptConnectionsThread.Join();
            acceptConnectionsThread = null;

            //  close listener
            listener.Close(); 
            listener = null;

            //  close host
            host.Close();
            host = null;
        }
    }

    private static WebServerHost
    host = null;

    private static HttpListener
    listener = null;

    private static Thread
    acceptConnectionsThread;

    private static void
    acceptConnections(object state)
    {
        while ( listener.IsListening )
        {
            try
            {
                HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(handleConnection, context);
            }
            catch ( HttpListenerException e )
            {
                //  this exception is ignored; it will be thrown when web server is stopped and at that time
                //  listening will be set to false which will end the loop and the thread
            }
        }
    }

    private static void
    handleConnection(object state)
    {
        host.ProcessRequest(new WebServerContext((HttpListenerContext)state));
    }
}
```

Finally, this `Initialization` class, marked with the NUnit [SetupFixture] attribute, is used to start the web server when the unit tests are started, and shut it down when they are completed.

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

[SetUpFixture]
public class Initialization
{
    [SetUp]
    public void
    Setup()
    {
        //  start the local web server
        WebServer.Start();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void
    TearDown()
    {
        //  stop the local web server
        WebServer.Stop();
    }
}
```

I know that this is not exactly answering the question, but I hope you find the information useful.

Comment: I wonder, what a particular test would look like? Would its body be wrapped in some kind of Execute call, to delegate actual execution to the created AppDomain?