# How can I prevent AppDomainUnloadedException after NUnit tests PLINQ code?

Tags: .net, nunit, appdomain, plinq, parallel-extensions

How can I diagnose and minimize or prevent `AppDomainUnloadedException`?

NUnit 2.5.2 consistently throws `AppDomainUnloadedException` after long (>10s) tests involving PLINQ.

Back in July 2008, [Stephen Toub said](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/archive/2008/06/02/8567802.aspx#8756683):

> Yes, the scheduler in the
>   CTP doesn't handle thread aborts very well, which frequently causes
>   the process to crash when a live scheduler exists in a domain being
>   shutdown (since AppDomain shut down causes thread aborts on all
>   threads with stack frames in that domain).  We're working to harden
>   this for a future release.

I've tried many workarounds, including:

- Running the test in a separate method to eliminate stray references
- Specifying `/domain:None` as an NUNit argument
- Removing the `legacyUnhandledAppDomainPolicy` element from `nunit-console.exe.config`

I can't backgrade NUnit to [reduce the odds of the race condition](http://osdir.com/ml/windows.dotnet.nunit.user/2007-04/msg00022.html), as I need PLINQ to make my parametric tests go faster. Versions of NUnit without the problem don't support parametric tests.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561402/cassini-webserver-webdev-nunit-and-appdomainunloadedexception for a related problem. This is probably https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunitv2/+bug/423611

Comment: Often such issue caused by wrong disposing of objects instantiated whilst a test startup, see whether you are disposing all resources in right way

Answer (score 1):

According to [this PLINQ Task Manager thread on the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/parallelextensions/thread/b838d6e4-4509-45c6-a40e-91f9c63246e2), your problem should be solved; with the latest release of the .NET framework, PLINQ's Task Manager has been to shutdown cleanly on AppDomain unload.

Are you still running into this problem with .NET 4 or 4.5?